# Is there a word to describe someone who disagrees with people just to be different?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I have a friend who always changes their mind depending on what others say just so he can be different and stand out, I've heard someone call it something before (I think I have, anyway) is there a name for this type of behavior?

Comment: Argumentative is one word.

Answer (score 2):

*devils advocate, contrarian*. Taking an opposing view for it's own sake. Exercising the other side of a debate to test the strength of your argument (something lawyers love)

Comment: "a contrarian" is the right word but your answer needs some improvement: links to sources, examples, references.

Answer (score 1):

**contrarian** is a noun. It doesn't necessarily imply that the person is antipathetic or argumentative; only that the person does something (e.g, investing in the *stock market*) in a way that seems opposite to the "common wisdom".

The adjective to describe someone who "disagrees just be different" is closely related:

- **contrary**

See #4: http://i.word.com/idictionary/contrary

Answer (score 0):

**Contradictor** : someone opposite of a statement or idea put forward by another.